# Match start and end datetime in Excel data series

Tags: excel, datetime, csv, vba

I have written a macro to format around 20 .csv files with the datetime of measurement in column b (i.e. 21/01/2015 03:15) and corresponding data in column c. It then copies the data from all of the .csv files into a new worksheet `Workbooks("CSV fix RPS data_v6.xlsm").Sheets("a")`

The start/finish time in each .csv is not the same. I want to amend the code so that it looks at the latest start time/earliest finish time in all of the date columns and copies data from this time period from all of the data and pastes it into a new sheet.

My code so far is below but I am a bit stuck on how to start with comparing datetimes.

```
Sub Get_raw_data_RPSCSV_30_03_15()


Dim row As Integer
Dim row_1 As Integer
Dim col As Integer
Dim col_2 As Integer
Dim col_3 As Integer

Dim time_last As Date
Dim EndRow As Long
Dim date_start As Date
Dim time_start As Date
Dim DateTime As Date

Dim FinalRow As Long
Dim Logg, Path, Filename, sheetname As String
Dim copyrange As Excel.Range



    With Workbooks("CSV fix RPS data_v6.xlsm").Worksheets("home") 'take the

        FinalRow = .Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).row

        For i = 3 To FinalRow '' keep this to reference the files

            Logg = .Cells(i, 4).Value 'logger name row "f:f"
            Path = .Cells(i, 2).Value '"b:b"
            Filename = .Cells(i, 3).Value '"c:c"

            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            Workbooks.Open Filename:=Path & Filename, Local:=True

            With Workbooks(Filename).Sheets(Logg)

                date_start = .Range("b17").Value ' merge date and time and fill down the row
                time_start = .Range("c17").Value
                Range("b18").Value = date_start + time_start
                EndRow = .Range("a" & .Rows.count).End(xlUp).row
                row = 18

                For row = 18 To EndRow - 1  '(minus 1 to stop it filling in an extra time value at the end)

                    col = 2
                    row_1 = row + 1
                    time_last = .Cells(row, col).Value
                    .Cells(row_1, col).Formula = DateAdd("n", 15, time_last)
                Next row

                .Range("c18:c" & EndRow).NumberFormat = "General" ' remove any weird number formatting
                .Range("c18:c" & EndRow).Value = .Range("a18:a" & EndRow).Value
                 'Set copyrange = .Range("b18:c" & EndRow)


                Set copyrange = .Range("b18:c" & EndRow) 'location of datetime and data

                Dim lRowCount As Long
                lRowCount = copyrange.Rows.count

                Dim lColumnCount As Long
                lColumnCount = copyrange.Columns.count

                Dim copyvalue As Variant
                copyvalue = copyrange.Value

            End With

                With Workbooks("CSV fix RPS data_v6.xlsm").Sheets("a") ' sheet to copy the data into
                    .Cells(1, i * 3 - 7).Value = Logg
                    .Cells(2, i * 3 - 8).Resize(lRowCount, lColumnCount).Value = copyvalue  'to paste the range of values rather than the first value only

               End With
                    copyvalue = Empty 'releases memory
        Next i

        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End With

    ''call a sub to compare date/time here''
End Sub
```

''''Update 14/04/15

I wrote a bit of code to define the `MaxStartDate`and `MinEndDate` below, however I am unsure of how to use this code to then select the dates/data for the range between these dates only.

```
Sub align_datetime()

Dim MaxStartDate As Date
Dim MinEndDate As Date
Dim LastCol As Long
Dim date_i As Integer
Dim DateMax As Date
Dim LastRow_date As Long
Dim LastRow_date_new As Long

    With Worksheets("a")

        LastCol = Sheets("a").Cells(1, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column

'' Go along the columns and find the latest date
        DateMax = Cells(2, 1).Value
        LastRow_date = .Range("a" & .Rows.count).End(xlUp).row
        Date_end = Cells(LastRow_date, 1).Value

          For date_i = 4 To LastCol Step 3

                    If Cells(2, date_i).Value > DateMax Then
                    DateMax = Cells(2, date_i).Value
                End If

                    LastRow_date_new = Application.CountA(Range((Cells(1, date_i)), (Cells(65536, date_i))))
                    Date_end = Cells(LastRow_date_new, date_i).Value

                    If Cells(LastRow_date_new, date_i).Value < Date_end Then
                        Date_end = Cells(LastRow_date_new, date_i).Value
                    End If

            Next date_i

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: It sounds to me like you need a `MaxStartDate` and `MinEndDate` added to the loop you've got to find those while you're going through your code, then another loop to go through (all your files again or the new sheet, I'm not sure) to select rows that are between `MaxStartDate` and `MinEndDate`.

Comment: Cheers @FreeMan, I used this idea and it works nicely as a starting point

Comment: I've edited the question above to get some help on selecting the data between the two times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution I came up with. I am pretty sure it could be much more refined but for the moment it is doing the job.

```
Sub align_datetime()

    Dim MaxStartDate As Date
    Dim MinEndDate As Date
    Dim LastCol As Long
    Dim date_i As Integer
    Dim DateMax As Date
    Dim LastRow_date As Long
    Dim LastRow_date_new As Long

        With Worksheets("a")

            LastCol = Sheets("a").Cells(1, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    '' Go along the columns and find the latest date
            DateMax = Sheets("a").Cells(2, 1).Value
            LastRow_date = Sheets("a").Range("a" & .Rows.count).End(xlUp).row
            Date_end = Sheets("a").Cells(LastRow_date, 1).Value

              For date_i = 4 To LastCol Step 3

                        If Sheets("a").Cells(2, date_i).Value > DateMax Then
                        DateMax = Sheets("a").Cells(2, date_i).Value
                    End If

                        LastRow_date_new = Application.CountA(Sheets("a").Range((.Cells(1, date_i)), (.Cells(65536, date_i))))
                        Date_end = Sheets("a").Cells(LastRow_date_new, date_i).Value

                        If Sheets("a").Cells(LastRow_date_new, date_i).Value < Date_end Then
                            Date_end = Sheets("a").Cells(LastRow_date_new, date_i).Value
                        End If

                Next date_i

                Dim SearchCol As Integer
                Dim row_i As Integer
                Dim row_j As Integer

             For SearchCol = 1 To LastCol Step 3

                 LastRow_date_new = Application.CountA(.Range((.Cells(1, SearchCol)), (.Cells(65536, SearchCol))))

                    For row_i = 2 To LastRow_date_new

                        If Sheets("a").Cells(row_i, SearchCol).Value = DateMax Then Start_row = row_i

                    Next row_i

                        For row_j = LastRow_date_new To 2 Step -1

                            If Sheets("a").Cells(row_j, SearchCol).Value = Date_end Then End_row = row_j

                        Next row_j

                    ''''''' use range col1, row i to col2, row j to copy into new sheet

                Dim startrange As Range
                Dim endrange As Range
                Dim startval As Range
                Dim endval As Range
                Dim dataCol As Integer

                Set startval = Sheets("a").Cells(Start_row, SearchCol)
                dataCol = SearchCol + 1
                Set endval = Sheets("a").Cells(End_row, dataCol)

                Dim DataRange As Range
                Dim dataRowCount As Long
                Dim dataColCount As Long
                Dim DataVal As Variant

                Set DataRange = Sheets("a").Range(startval.Address, endval.Address)'select range between the start and end dates
                dataRowCount = DataRange.Rows.count 'to make sure the range you copy the data to is the same size as the range of data you copy
                dataColCount = DataRange.Columns.count
                DataVal = DataRange.Value

                    With Workbooks("CSV fix RPS data_v7.xlsm").Sheets("b") ' sheet to copy the data into
                        .Cells(2, SearchCol).Resize(dataRowCount, dataColCount).Value = DataVal  'to paste the range of values rather than the first value only
                        Sheets("b").Cells(1, SearchCol + 1).Value = Sheets("a").Cells(1, SearchCol + 1).Value
                    End With

                    DataVal = Empty 'releases memory

           Next SearchCol


        End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can DIM two variables as suggested by FreeMan.

```
Dim MaxStart as date, MInEnd as date
```

In your loop assign the values like this:

```
maxstart = Max(MaxStart, NextDate)
minStart = Min(MinStart, NextDate)
```

Alternatively you can use the DateDiff function to determine if the nextdate is larger or smaller than what you already have in maxstart and minstart.

```
if datediff("D", maxstart, nextdate) > 0 then
  maxstart = nextdate
endif
if datediff("D", minstart, nextdate) < 0 then
  minstart = nextdate
endif
```

DateDiff supports time differences also should you want more precision than just days, or if you only want to compare days difference when the times are part of the date.

Comment: Cheers. That sounds good.  I used the previous suggestion by @Freeman but I will bear this in mind for next time. I've edited the question above to get some help on selecting the data between the two times.